# Javascript search if LocalStorage variable exists

Tags: javascript

I am programming a chat system. I always make a Localstorage variable when a new chat is opened. Created like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("chat_"+varemail, data);
```

Now i want to check how many of them I have so something like:
"chat_"+... count.
How can I do this?

Comment: Is there anything else in `localStorage`? If not, then just check the `.length` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd grab the array of keys of the `localStorage` object, and use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to grab only the items starting with "chat_":

```
var length = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
    return /^chat_.+/.test(key);
}).length;
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y8zuwkju/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, loop through all items in `localStorage` and match against your pattern

```
function getChatCount(){
    var chatCount = 0;
    for(item in localStorage){
       if(item.indexOf('chat_') > -1) chatCount++;
    }
    return chatCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is based on key, value pairs. AFAIK, you wouldn't be able to retrieve all values with a certain prefix.

One potential solution would be to store an object that contains these. Based on your needs you could store the objects in an array or object and then retrieve the entire set and find the count.

For example:

```
var chats = { count: 0 };
chats["chat_"+varemail] = data;
chats.count += 1;

localStorage.setItem('chats', data);
```

Then if you want a count, you would retrieve the object:

```
var chats = localStorage.getItem('chats');
//chats.count would give you the count.
```

Although, this would mean you have to manually maintain the count variable when adding or removing data. If you don't need the indexing ability, you could add the chats to an array and store that.

EDIT: It is possible to find properties with a certain prefix, as seen in an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer to convert to `localStorage.setItem("chat", JSON.stringify(stack))`, where `stack` is an array of chat objects. This way, you have access to an array of chats which you can count, search within, etc.

Something like:

```
var chatStore =
    {
        Count: function () {
            var stack = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chats"));
            if (!stack)
                return 0;
            return stack.length;
        },
        Peek: function () {
            var stack = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chats"));
            if (!stack)
                stack = [];
            if (stack.length > 0)
                return stack.pop();
        },
        Push: function (token) {
            var stack = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chats"));
            if (!stack)
                stack = [];
            stack.push(token);
            localStorage.setItem("chats", JSON.stringify(stack));
        },
        // more methods to you might wish to implement: search, insert, etc.
    }

// usage:
chatStore.Push(chatObject); // sets the last chat
chatStore.Peek(); // gets the last chat
```